# Efficient way to solve $31^6 \mod 189$ without using any external devices.

Tags: real-analysis, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

Assuming basic knowledge of modulus arithmetic, is there a way, a trick or formulas that allow you to solve modulus question with very large numbers without using calculator? For example,

$$76^7 \mod 187=32$$ $$7^{23} \mod 143=2$$

This question ties into RSA Encryption where I'm trying to figure out how to solve these questions. So if I have $31^6 \mod 189$, I can simply use Wolfram Alpha but how can I work out that $31^6 \mod 189$?

Comment: look up Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Using Chinese Remainder Theorem and Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Chinese remainder theorem int tandem with Eulers theorem will reduce is as far as possible.  As to whether the calculations are *easy* or not is another issue.

So $31^6 \mod 189$.  $189 = 7*3^3$ so by chinese remainder theorem we can solve this by solving $31^6 \mod 7$ and $31^6 \mod 27$.

So $7$ is prime and $31$ is not a multiple of $7$ we know $31^{7-1}\equiv 1 \mod 7$ so ... that's that.  And $\phi(27) = 3^2*2 = 18$ so $31^6 \equiv .... \mod 37$.  Well, it's a cube root of one but ... $31^6 \equiv 4^6 \equiv (3+1)^6 \equiv {6 \choose 2}3^2 + 6*3 + 1 \equiv \frac {6*5}2*3^2 + 18 + 1\equiv 19\mod 27$ ... or $4^6 \equiv 64^2 \equiv 10^2 \equiv 100 \equiv 19 \mod 27$.

So $31^6 \equiv 1 + 7k \equiv 19 + 27j \mod 189$.  By CRT there is one solution.

So solve $1 + 7k = 19 + 27j$

$27 = 4*7 - 1$

$1 = 4*7 - 27$.

$1 + 7k = 19 + 27j$

$7k - 27j = 18 = 21 - 3 = 3*7 - 3(4*7 - 27) = -9*7 +3*27$.

So if $k = -9$ and $j = -3$ we get $1-7*9 = -62$ and $19 - 3*27 =-62$

And so $31^6 \equiv -62 \equiv 127 \mod 189$

Answer (score 0):

Go in small steps. For instance first compute 
$$76^2 \mod 187$$
by hand, giving 166. Now, $166= -21\mod 187$. Also, $76^3=(-21)\cdot 76 = 87 \mod 187$. So you have

$$(76^2)\cdot(76^2)\cdot(76^3) = (-21)\cdot(-21)\cdot(87)=67\cdot87=32\mod 187.$$

You can do the other one in a similar fashion.

Answer (score -1):

$31^2=961$ and $5\times 189=945$ so that $31^6\equiv 16^3$ and if you know your powers of $2$ this is efficiently sorted.

Comment: That's a correct answer for one of the specific case in the answer, but I think OP wants a general answer.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Perhaps you are right, but the headline question requires a simple way for this specific one, and little Fermat doesn't help much in this specific case. This is how I did this example in my head. I find that using the Chinese Remainder Theorem in an effective form (rather than just to prove a solution exists) is computationally inefficient in small cases. So I find that getting used to spotting short cuts and alternative routes to compute is more efficient than some of the general methods in small cases, unless Fermat applies directly.

Answer (score -1):

There is a shortcut for any calculation of two digit number in power of 2.
For instance you need to count 442 (forty four in power of 2), you do like this:

1. Split this two digit number(44) ->  4  4
2. Then you rise two digits(separately) in a power of two and in the middle you will put double product of the first digit to the second ->

   ---

   4<sup>2</sup>_ **2*4*4** _4<sup>2</sup>
3. Then you've got the following : 16_32_16
4. So now you need to derive the answer from that, the answer is not that number
   **163216** . Actually what you've got from step 3 is , 3 digits which make up your answer ,and you have to put it appropriate slots . 
   **16 32 16** ->**_ _ _**  -> we need to put first value in the first slot as our value consist of two digit value , we put only 6 there and 1 we keep in mind
    **_ _ 6** (1->in mind)
   then put second value in the second slot , again 32 is two digit value , so do the same operation , put there 2 , keep 3 in mind , and main part you have to sum up the previous numbers in mind to the next hop  **_ (1+2) 6**(3-in mind),
   then put third value in third place and add the number (3) you have in mind
   **(6+3)36** (1 in mind), so as you can see you are left with one more number ,so the last number in mind you put in front of .

Here is the result:
 **1936**

Now you can easily rise two digits number in power of two. This will give you great benefit in speed and calculation as well.

76<sup>2</sup>*76<sup>2</sup>*76<sup>2</sup>*76